# How to edit legend in ggfortify in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, ggfortify

I am using carData::Rossi data to estimate a survival curve. This is the code I used to generate the plot:

```
library(carData); library(survival)
km1 <- survfit(Surv(week,arrest) ~ race,type = "kaplan-meier",data=Rossi)

library(ggplot2); library(ggfortify)
autoplot(km1) + 
  labs(x="Time", y="Proportion", strata= "Raza")
```

I got this result:

[image]

How can I change the strata label to Race?

Comment: i think it should be `colour = ` instead of `strata`

Comment: @rawr `colour = "Raza"` doesn't work for me...Is there different between `color` and `colour`? Maybe it's my problem that this not works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `strata = "Raza"`, you using both `color = "Raza"` and `fill = "Raza"` will works.

```
library(GlobalDeviance)
library(ggfortify)

km1 <- survfit(Surv(week,arrest) ~ race,type = "kaplan-meier",data=Rossi)

autoplot(km1) + 
  labs(x="Time", y="Proportion", color = "Raza", fill = "Raza")
```

[image]

I'm not sure that `colour = "Raza"` works. It did't work for me.

By using `survminer::ggsurvplot`,

```
survminer::ggsurvplot(km1, xlab = "Time", ylab = "Proportion", 
                      legend.title = "Raza", conf.int = TRUE, ylim = c(0.65,1),
                      legend = "right", surv.scale = "percent")
```

[image]

Comment: It actually worked, but now I am getting double legend. How can I just keep one?

Comment: @JesúsAsdrúbalMolinaVíquez When I try adding both, It gave me single legend, so I write them as an answer.  May you add that double legend plot to your question?

Comment: @JesúsAsdrúbalMolinaVíquez I add solution using `survminer::ggsurvplot`. Would you mind to check it out?